# Stop addClass from firing multiple times

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I'm attempting to add a class to my navigation when a user scrolls, the class will be added to an element depending on the `.scrollTop()` value. I have this working fine but what is happening is that every time the user scrolls, `addClass` is constantly firing and because I have CSS3 animations on the class being added it creates a very obvious artefact.

[See my rough implementation here](http://jsbin.com/uyobic/1/)

I do realise that there are options like 'scrollspy' and 'waypoints' but I'd love to find a way to implement this without them (I haven't tested to see if this occurs with those libraries)

Is there anyway to prevent this from happening? Thanks.

Edit: Attaching code as per a request.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrollPos <= 100){
        $(".nav-home").addClass("selected");    
    }
    if(scrollPos > 100 && scrollPos <= 500){
        $(".nav-showcase").addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question

Comment: Do you only want it to fire once when you hit a certain `.scrollTop();` value?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I did post it, here it is again http://jsbin.com/uyobic/1/

Comment: @KevinKulla I want it to only fire once when it enters a range. Like 0 to 100, 101 to 500 etc.

Comment: @ponens: A link to an external site is always helpful, but it would be even better to include the code *in* the question.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Oh I see, I just didn't see how that would help since it's spread across html, css and javascript and you would not be able to see what I am trying to explain as it's a very visual thing. I will add it in now.

Answer (score 2):

You may check if the class is already added and if yes do not add it again.

```
if(!$(".nav-home").hasClass("selected")){
$(".nav-home").addClass("selected")
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I did attempt this but it did not work. I also read on a stackoverflow question that addClass already checks if a class exists anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read your code like a story:

```
if(scrollPos < 100){
  $(".nav-home").addClass("selected");  
}
if(scrollPos > 100 && scrollPos < 500){
 $(".nav-showcase").addClass("selected");
}
```

if my scroll is smaller as 100, add the class selected on `.nav-home`
if my scroll is between 100 && 500 add the class selected on `.nav-showcase`

I hope you already understand why it is firing so many times?

If not: there is a scroll between 100 - 500 (400 pixel), than could be a lot of scrolls, so it is firing all the time if you are between those 2 values.

As a solution i would say, go for MRIDA's solution:

```
if(scrollPos < 100){
  if(!$(".nav-home").hasClass("selected")){
    $(".nav-home").addClass("selected");
  }
}
if(scrollPos > 100 && scrollPos < 500){
  if(!$(".nav-showcase").hasClass("selected")){
    $(".nav-showcase").addClass("selected");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I definitely understand what is happening and WHY it's firing multiple times, I guess I just need to know how to prevent it from firing multiple times. The first thing I tried was 'hasClass' and it did not work. I read on another stackoverflow post that addClass checks if the class exists anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned earlier by @Mark, *"You need to read your code like a story"*; I simply did not read my *story* with enough depth. I was removing my class at the incorrect location thus causing the problem that I had. I have corrected the snippet in the jsbin that I posted above if anyone is interested.

Thanks for all the replies.